# Asus Laptop Drivers

Tags: drivers, touchpad, asus

Please let me know, which are the Asus Model Type **(Laptop)** fully compatible with **Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS** (Bionic Beaver), and **Ubuntu 18.10** (Cosmic Cuttlefish) in-terms of all Drivers & Etc ?

Comment: I'm afraid this question is too broad. At least ASUS UX430U works fine out of the box with Ubuntu 18.04. On the contrary, model UX433F is giving me a hard time with Ubuntu 18.04: it doesn't boot after first update. And with Ubuntu 19.04, even the installer cannot boot.